# Writing a multiplication MATLAB style

Tags: matlab

MATLAB's syntax differs somewhat from the traditional DO loops "logic" which iterates over indexes one at a time. With that in mind, what would be a more proper way to write the following, so it runs a bit faster but is still relatively clear for someone not too familiar with MATLAB.

```
KT = 0.;
for i=1:37
   dKT = KTc(i,1) *const2^KTc(i,2) *const3^KTc(i,3) *const4^KTc(i,4) *const5^KTc(i,5);
   KT = KT + dKT;
end
sprintf('KT = %f10.8', KT);
```

KTc is a matrix 37x5
(if it helps, only the (i,1) values are REAL values, the rest are INTEGERs)

All constants are REAL scalars.

Comment: Aren't you overwriting KT each loop iteration? Am I wrong? What you really want to do?

Comment: Yeah, it is full of typos. I have tried to upkeep his question but it has not got accepted.

Comment: The problem was that I edited your question but they did not accept it for some reason. But Im not far away being able to do this kinds of edits on my own. :) I was not the down-voter, but care to correct your question, please?

Comment: Further, note that matlab does not use `**`, but `^`. Instead of "do ... end do" matlab uses "for i=1:37 ... end"

Comment: ok, that leaves two coices 1.) you intentionally made your question unambiguous 2.) you did not care to look at matlab syntax at all. Either way, it is -1.

Comment: Therefore you have got the help in the comments. [But it is your task to update the text of your question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs - Tried to clarify it a bit, and rectified a major error. Also, thank you for the last comment, but if you checked you might've seen that I've been on this site a few days now, and am familiar with the rules in general. That still however doesn't presume that I can answer to everything within a minute of time.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it cleared the situation for me. I've removed the down-vote, as I see your question might be rather about how to do that few lines correctly. See my answer in that respect too.

Comment: sorry, I just saw my edit went through. :( I think many others misunderstood your question the same way like me. You can do a rollback to the original question if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Your lines (in the original question) correctly:

```
KT = 0.;
for i=1:37
   dKT = KTc(i,1) *const2^KTc(i,2) *const3^KTc(i,3) *const4^KTc(i,4) *const5^KTc(i,5);
   KT = KT + dKT;
end
sprintf('KT = %f10.8', KT);
```

On the other hand I would suggest

```
KT = repmat([1; const2; const3; const4; const5], 1, n) .^ KTc;
KT(1,:) = KTc(1,:);
KT = sum(KT(:));
```

Loops are rarely used in a real matlab-style program. The reason for that is, that although my second solution does more operations, in practice it is quicker due to more optimal caching at the processor, parallelization, and other possible optimizations which are done silently in the background.

UPDATE: (explanation on repmat)

I think repmat is short for "replicate matrix". What it does really is best explained with two typical examples:

```
v_row=[1 2 3];
repmat(v_row, 2, 1);
%result:
[1 2 3
 1 2 3]

v_col=[1;2;3];      % I could also write v_col=v_row';
repmat(v_col, 1, 2);
[1 1
 2 2
 3 3]
```

In general repmat does this:

```
repmat(m, 2, 3);
[m m m
 m m m] 
% if m=[1 2; 3 4] was the value of m, then
 [1     2     1     2     1     2
  3     4     3     4     3     4
  1     2     1     2     1     2
  3     4     3     4     3     4]
```

Comment: Would it be too much asking, if you could just explain (in simple terms) what repmat does? I can't quite figure it out from the help (will have to read it some more).

Comment: Not at all. Updated answer with repmat explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
KT = KT_coeff(1,1:37) .* const1.^KT_coeff(2,1:37) .* const2.^KT_coeff(3,1:37) .* const3.^KT_coeff(4,1:37) .*  const4.^KT_coeff(5,1:37);
```

Given that you know the size of each KT_coeff is 37 in the 2nd dimension, you could simplify this a bit further with by replacing `1:37` with just `:` above.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid all these exponentials, taking a log first and then an exp.

```
    % // way cheaper to evaluate
  log_KT = log([c1 c2 c3 c4])*KT_coeff(2:end,:); 
    % // Final exp
  KT = KT_coeff(1,:) .* exp(log_KT);  

 KT = sum(KT);
```